# Usability testing dashboard

Tags: user-behavior, user-research, usability-testing, user-centered-design, dashboard

I want to usability test the current dashboard before I start any designs to understand how current users are using it and what are their pain points. In the past when I have done such testing I have been able to give the user a task and see what issues they have encountered to complete it.

However, with a dashboard I am struggling to think of any task I wish for them to complete as it is all on the one page.

When the usability test just involves one page and not much interaction to record, do I show the user the design and ask questions to understand their behaviour or is there another aspect I can include in the test that will give me further insight into their behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asking questions and probing the user to detail feedback is probably the way to go for this rather than setting out action based tasks.

I recommend to begin by probing the users about what they use the dashboard for currently, and what are the main things they are looking at when using this page.

Then you can dive into questions like:

> "How difficult was it to find XYZ"

You can do this for each section of the page this will give you some kind of rough scale to measure performance upon.

In addition to this I would recommend asking the users about anything that is missing from the page, what their wishes are what functionality might be useful.

Comment: Dashboards are great for cardsorting exercises where you sketch out all the individual possible items that could go on the dashboard and ask them to lay out the sort of dashboard they'd find the most useful. Of course that can only be done *before* you build it rather than afterwards.